# Moving Firefox 13's startpage elements by editing omni.ja crashes FF, anyone know how to do this properly?

Tags: c, windows, firefox, archive, php-ziparchive

After removing the settings elements on Firefox 13's startpage, the google searchbox and logo are too low and I'd like to move them. I can edit the startpage by opening omni.ja with IZArc and going to chrome\browser\content\browser\abouthome\aboutHome.xhtml and editing the file, but when I save the omni.ja file to the FF directory, it fails to launch the programme. Does anyone know how to do this properly? I think I'm missing a step.

Answer (score 2):

Just got this working!  Used Unzip to extract the files (just drag omni.ja onto it).

Get unzip from http://stahlforce.com/dev/index.php?tool=zipunzip (Info-zip's own site does not allow you to download it anymore).

What I did:

1. Created a folder on my desktop to hold the extracted files. (TEST)
2. Dragged **Unzip.exe** and **omni.ja** into this folder.
3. Dragged **omni.ja** onto **Unzip.exe** to extract all the files.
4. Remove/deleted **Unzip.exe** and **omni.ja** from this folder.
5. Made my changes to the folder. (in this case I was editing the **firefox.js** file... not applicable to you)
6. Rezip all the folders using windows zip. (highlight all the files and folders, right-click, send to, Compressed (zipped) folder)
7. Rename this zip file as **omni.ja** and copy it back to the root of your Firefox directory.

I have to say that I did have to edit my js file in notepad though; using whatever was set as windows default editor would just error.

Source: [Locking down Firefox 14](http://scantheman.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/locking-down-firefox-14.html) (blog post)

Comment: @Simon **bolding** words is NOT better formatting. Please stop making such edits.